# LM311 Pull Up Resistor

Tags: pullup

If I use an LM311 Comparator, then we are required to connect a pull up resistor at the output. Does the square wave output depends on the value of the voltage the resistor pulls up to?

Would it be that if i had a 5V on the pull up, then the output would be a square wave with 0V to 5V(max).
And for a 12V pull up - a 12V to 0V Square wave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the pull-up resistor will pull the output up to whatever voltage it is connected to, unless something else connected to that output prevents the output from rising to the full supply voltage.